# symfony get mimeTypes from Entity File Constraint

Tags: file, symfony, constraints, mime-types

In my API Controller i need to get the allowed mimeTypes from a File Constraint (Assert)

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

...

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize="3M",
     *     mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"}
     * )
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="live_thumbnail_image", fileNameProperty="ThumbURI")
     *
     * @var File $Picture
     */
    protected $Picture;
```

I have tried

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
/** @var ClassMetadata $meta */
$meta = $validator->getMetadataFor(ChannelMetadata::class);
$constraints = $meta->getPropertyMetadata('Picture');
```

then i have a array of PropertyMetadataInterface and so on.

Is there an easier way to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to get annotation values.

```
    $annotation = $reader->getPropertyAnnotation('Picture', \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File::class);
```

The $reader is this service @annotation_reader